# How to bind data to a NSTableView from a NSDictionary?

Tags: macos, nstableview, nstablecolumn

Does anybody knows how to fill up a NSTableView using binding values from a NSDictionary?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create an `NSDictionaryController` in Interface Builder.  Bind it to your dictionary, and then bind the `NSTableView` to the objects in the `NSDictionaryController`.

**Look here:**
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDictionaryController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html

If you don't yet fully understand Cocoa Bindings and KV coding, you should start reading here first:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000167i

Comment: Hey.. thanks! I'll give it a try... Related to bindings, let's say I understand the concept, but I don't fully get how to apply those in practice =D, maybe the links you provide will help.. bye

Comment: Sorry, but do you know about any link with some tutorial about NSTableView, and dynamically add columns?  I am trying to reach something like the screenshot 5.5 in this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html

Comment: That is a window from the iSpend sample code. So look here for that: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/iSpend/Introduction/Intro.html