# NSDictionary content to NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

how I can use an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary's` in an `NSTableView` using Cocoa? Can any one pls suggest me with proper solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081632/how-to-bind-data-to-a-nstableview-from-a-nsdictionary

Comment: are you intended to use binding or coding?

Comment: In other words, Cocoa Bindings, or writing your own controller code?

Comment: Voting as not a duplicate, since the duplicate question is about Cocoa Bindings, and it's not clear that OP really intends to use bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // I will use tempDict Object for your understandings, otherwise it can be used directly. Here array1 is Main DataSource for UITableView.
    NSDictionary *tempDict = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // key1 is the key to get the object from the dictionary.
    cell.title.text = [tempDict valueForKey:key1];

    return cell;
}
```

Here, array1 is the main `DataSource` for your table view, which contains `NSDictionary` objects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please click the check-mark outline next to the answer.